# EOS on pipeline not executing

Tags: python, gstreamer

I am new to GStreamer and trying to create a simple example where I am getting video from the webcam and saving it using filesink. I have added a watch on bus to get EOS event but it never gets executed. Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here and how can I stop pipeline and get EOS Event working?

import gi
import time

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
import signal

Gst.init(None)

class Main:
    def **init**(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.keyboardInterruptHandler)

```
    self._pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("avfvideosrc name=avfvideosrc ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink name=filesink location=output.mp4")
    bus = self._pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect("message::eos", self._on_eos_from_sink_pipeline)
    self._pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

def _on_eos_from_sink_pipeline(self, _bus, _message):
    print("Got EOS from sink pipeline")

def keyboardInterruptHandler(self,signal, frame):
    print("KeyboardInterrupt (ID: {}) has been caught. Cleaning up...".format(signal))
    self.stopFetching()
    time.sleep(5)
    exit()

def stopFetching(self):
    print("AT THE START OF STOP FETCHING")
    self._pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    self._pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
    print("AT THE END OF STOP FETCHING")
```

start = Main()
Gtk.main()

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. the solution is to send the EOS event only to the src element, not to every element in the pipeline or to pipeline

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. What do you mean with sending the EOS event to the src element? Could you update your answer with some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: oh my lord! Thank you @ravi. Spent a whole day. I'm really frustrated with gstreamer lack of documentation and reliability.

Answer (score 1):

@ravi's answer above worked for me!

For C++ devs and also those who have the specific use case of using a muxer for combining audio and video onto a mp4 file, here is how I handled sending the EOS message:

```
std::string FlowyMedia::StopRecord()
{
    if (m_record_pipeline == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "MEDIA: record pipeline not initialized" << std::endl;
        return std::string("");
    }

    std::cout << "Stopping record, sending eos" << std::endl;

    GstElement *video_src = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(m_record_pipeline), "videosrc");
    g_assert(video_src);
    GstElement *audio_src = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(m_record_pipeline), "audiosrc");
    g_assert(audio_src);
    gst_element_send_event(video_src, gst_event_new_eos());
    gst_element_send_event(audio_src, gst_event_new_eos());

    // get full path to file
    return std::string("./test.mp4");
}
```

I then have this as my bus watcher callback. The set_state for the EOS case is what properly stops my pipeline and finishes writing to a proper mp4 file.

```
gboolean FlowyMedia::HandleGstMessage(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gpointer user_data)
{
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message))
    {
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        {
            g_print("End of stream message received \n");

            gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(user_data), GST_STATE_NULL);
            break;
        }
        case GST_MESSAGE_WARNING:
        {
            gchar*  debug;
            GError* error;
            gst_message_parse_warning(message, &error, &debug);
            g_printerr(
                "WARNING from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME(message->src), error->message);
            g_printerr("Warning details: %s\n", debug);
            g_free(debug);
            g_error_free(error);
            break;
        }
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        {
            gchar*  debug;
            GError* error;
            gst_message_parse_error(message, &error, &debug);
            g_printerr(
                "ERROR from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME(message->src), error->message);
            g_printerr("Error details: %s\n", debug);
            g_free(debug);
            g_error_free(error);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return GST_BUS_PASS;
}
```